# How to addclass if child li has specific content?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add class on `li` based on the content. My code is adding the class on both `li` parent and child, but i need to add only that `li` which has specific content.
[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/imayazshah/u51bnpzo/)

```
<ul class="Team">
    <li>Manager
        <ul>
            <li>Team Leader</li>
            <li>Php Developer</li>
            <li>Graphic Designer</li>
            <li>Game Developer</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Admin
        <ul>
            <li>Assistant Accountant</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to add the class `.trend` on that `li` which has `Game Developer` content.

`$('.Team li:contains(Game Developer)').addClass('trend');`

But above code adding to class on both `li` parent and child. Can any one guide me how can i select `li` based on the content. I will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to ignore the `li` with `ul` by using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector,

```
$('.Team li:contains(Game Developer):not(:has(ul))').addClass('trend');
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u51bnpzo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class for **`<li>`** elements with **assistant** class

Try this:

```
$('.Team li.assistant:contains("Game Developer")').addClass('trend');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or get specific.

```js
$('.Team > li > ul > li:contains(Game Developer)').addClass('trend');
```